# My site a core php site and it is relate with the wordpress blog any security measures we have to take or not

Tags: php, wordpress

My site is a core php site and it is relate to a wordpress blog.
For e.g www.example.com/blog
Here the blog ia s wordpress page and other than that all site is normal php page.
So my server support told that the relationship between the wordpress blog and a php page is not very secure.

So how could i do to make it secure.

Comment: As long as you keep your Wordpress up to date, I don't see why this is not secure...

Comment: Ask your server support for more details.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of things you can do, a quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&num=10&hl=en&safe=active&q=improve+wordpress+security&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=c6affe93747c32d0) offers plentiful resources on ways to improve wordpress security.

Most of them mention a few key things:

1. **Keep Wordpress up to date.** This is super important as, when security flaws are discovered in wordpress, they are generally pretty quick to provide a fix.
2. **Don't use "admin" as your administrator login name.** This used to be the default, which made it easy to guess, Wordpress 3.0 now asks you to provide a username of your choice. Don't use "admin"
3. **Use a strong password.** Try using a password generator somewhere that gives you a *long* password with alphanumeric characters of varying case as well as symbols.
4. **Don't grant unlimited access to the wordpress database user.** For example, your wordpress database user probably doesn't need permissions to DROP tables.

There are more, somewhat superfluous, things you can do to further hide things from outside users. Take a look at the pages that come up with the [Google search I mentioned earlier](http://www.google.com/webhp#sclient=psy&num=10&hl=en&safe=active&site=webhp&q=improve+wordpress+security&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=c6affe93747c32d0).